# trying to find the lowest average height in this .dat file of numbers

Tags: ruby, loops

Im trying to fit a swimming pool onto this piece of terrain. The terrain is the first index (10x10 in this case) and the last index is the size the pool will be(2x2).
ive figured out how to read in the terrain and get the mean and standard deviation of it but now i need to find the lowest average height.  I know i need to use a while loop but I dont know how to go about this can anyone help me ?

```
10
1 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 12 12 12
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 12 12 12
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 12 12 12
21
```

Comment: Define what you mean lowest average height.

Comment: forgot to mention the nums in the grid represent the height of the location.and for instance if the pool is two by two then for every 2x2 grid get the average height

Comment: Since you've already figured out how to read it in, it would be great to see your reading code and the data structures you already have, so that we can help provide feedback by using those. In your above sample input, what is 21? I thought the last index was supposed to give the size, and I don't see how 21 is related to `2x2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two answers showing different styles. The first is faster (only important for HUGE terrain sizes), but less "Ruby-esque"; the second is more functional, but creates extra intermediary data. For your own best education, I encourage you to ensure that you understand these thoroughly, and choose how to proceed in a way that is best for you.

Also, I've assumed that the `21` you have in your question is a mistake, and you meant to have a `2` there.

First, both solutions start with the same code that creates an array of arrays for the terrain:

```
# Load the text file as an array of strings
lines = IO.readlines('pool.txt')

# Turn it into an array of arrays of numbers
terrain = lines.map{ |s| s.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) }

# Throw out the silly grid size; we'll infer it from real data instead!
terrain.shift 

# Take the last line (pool size) out of the terrain
pool_size = terrain.pop.first
```

The first solution walks through the terrain and calculates the average for each sub-grid, keeping track of the lowest number:

```
# For fun, we'll allow terrain that doesn't have to be square
rows = terrain.length
cols = terrain.first.length

best_size = Float::INFINITY
0.upto(rows-pool_size-1) do |y|
  0.upto(cols-pool_size-1) do |x|
    # x,y is the upper left corner of a valid pool_size × pool_size grid
    average = 0.0
    0.upto(pool_size-1) do |m|
      0.upto(pool_size-1) do |n|
        # Add up each point in the sub-grid
        average += terrain[y+n][x+m]
      end
    end

    # The number of points we added is the square of the size
    average /= (pool_size*pool_size)

    # Mark this as the best seen so far
    best_size = average if average < best_size
  end
end

p best_size
#=> 1.25
```

The second solution finds all the sub-grids, and then uses the [`Enumerable#min_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) method to find the best. We also create a method for calculating the average on an array of numbers, just for fun and more self-describing code:

```
# See http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html
require 'matrix' 

class Matrix
  # Average all values in the array (as a float)
  def average
    parts = to_a.flatten
    parts.inject(:+) / parts.length.to_f
  end
end

# Hey look, a nice 2D grid of elevations!
terrain = Matrix[ *terrain ]

# Create an array of matrices, each one representing a possible pool
rows = 0...(terrain.row_size    - size)
cols = 0...(terrain.column_size - size)
pools = rows.flat_map{|x| cols.map{ |y| terrain.minor(x,size,y,size) } }

# Find the lowest pool by calling the above 'average' method on each
lowest = pools.min_by(&:average)

p lowest, lowest.average
#=> Matrix[[1, 1], [1, 2]]
#=> 1.25
```

On my computer the simple array-of-arrays method takes ~0.6s to find the lowest 3x3 pool in a random 400×400 terrain, while the matrix technique takes ~1.3s. So the matrix style is more than twice as slow, but still plenty fast for your assignment. :)

Comment: Also, I should note that the first solution with the `m/n` loop can be made faster by replacing that loop with: `0.upto(pool_size-1){|m| average += terrain[y+m][x,pool_size] }`; I'll leave it up to you to understand what that does.

Comment: This is a student assignment, and providing help, while well-intentioned of course, is NOT serving the software community.

Comment: @ComDubh I respectfully disagree. There is no definitive evidence that this is homework. Even if it is: I do not feel that it is appropriate to impose any moral code I may hold on others; providing working code _may_ help this student to learn; providing working code CERTAINLY helps others with a similar question who find this post. I encourage you to read through all of [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/153741).

Comment: I'm not imposing a moral code on anyone, just expressing an opinion, the same as you are! Could a *10x10* terrain with elevations in *integers* conceivably be a real-world problem? I don't think so, but others might. You provide two really nice solutions which is informative for the Ruby community of course, though I would have said it violates the guidelines you referred me to ('usually better not to provide a complete code sample'). We can agree to differ :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's Ruby. You probably want to use iterators, not `while` loops.

But do your own homework. You'll learn more.